# In sieve, how can I copy a message to another user's mailbox on the same server without re-sending it externally?

Tags: email, filter, imap, cyrus-imapd

I am using sieve to filter email in our IMAP server (Cyrus imapd). I have basic knowledge of how this works and have made a few simple sieve scripts that behave as expected so far. To attach those scripts to a user mailbox on the server, I first connect to the server using `sieveshell` and then execute the appropriate commands there.

Now, for the first time, I would like to copy certain messages from the user mailbox where they arrive **to another user mailbox on the same server**. But I can't figure out how to achieve that. Is it possible at all?

As an example, let's say I have two user mailboxes called `user1` and `user2` on that server, and I want to copy all messages that arrive for `user1` to the `INBOX` of `user2`, provided they are from a certain sender (identified by the `From:` header). Then I probably should make a sieve script that contains something like

```
if address :is "from" "sender@example.org"
{
  /*
  What do I need to put in here? The following does not work or is not what I want:

  redirect :copy "user2@mydomain.com"  <--- Probably sends message via SMTP (not desired)
  fileinto :copy "user/user2/INBOX"    <--- Does not work because the path is relative to the current user's mailbox
  */
}
```

and load it into the account of `user2` (via `sieveshell`).

However, as the comments in that script imply, I don't know what I should put into the action line. I have studied a lot of sieve tutorials and examples, but didn't find a single hint about how to copy messages to **another user's mailbox on the same IMAP server.** The fact that I didn't find such examples probably tells me that it is a stupid idea, but I don't get why.

Currently I believe that `redirect` would be the wrong action to use, because all examples I saw use it to forward the message to a fully qualified email address. This probably means that a SMTP server is needed to forward the message, which I don't want.

The `fileinto` action seems inappropriate as well, because the destination folder is relative to the user (mailbox / account) the script is attached to. This means that it can't be used to forward messages to somebody else at all.

I have read the parts of the sieve RFCs that list the possible actions, but couldn't find a suitable action besides `redirect` and `fileinto`, so I am stuck now.

I am aware that I could probably solve the simple example problem shown above at the SMTP side, before the message is actually fetched and passed along to the IMAP server. However, the example is over-simplified, so I would really like to learn how to use sieve to copy messages to other local accounts on the same server.

Comment: Quoting the [RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5228): "The intention is to make it impossible for users to do anything more complex (and dangerous) than write simple mail filters". A user is usually restricted to their own mailbox, so as far as I can tell your usecase is out of scope for `sieve` and should be handled at SMTP level.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. While it feels "better" to not go via SMTP for reasons I cannot express, I am wondering why I feel that way about SMTP. Currently, I am aiming for simply using a full-fledged redirect via SMTP. So first question: Did you find a solution without SMTP? Second question: Why do you hesitate to use SMTP? As I said: I feel that one shouldn't use SMTP, too, but actually have no technical argument against using it.

Comment: The reason why we avoid SMTP is trivial: We do not operate an SMTP server inhouse. And for sure we won't setup one for this purpose. That is, such messages would leave our environment and go over an external SMTP server just to be copied to another internal user. This is ridiculous. Due to the bad software quality (segfaults here and there), the extremely bad documentation and the extremely bad support (the developers just don't care about important bugs and are unwilling or not able to answer even the simplest questions on the mailing list), we'll surely move away from Cyrus ASAP.

Comment: As for the solution: We have switched from `fetchmail` to `fdm` to pull the messages from external servers into our environment. In contrast to `fetchmail`, `fdm` has a decent filter language that is easily understandable and works reliably. Since the filtering (including copying to other internal accounts) now is done by `fdm`, we have dumped `sieve` as well (`sieve` has further problems nobody of the Cyrus team is willing even to reproduce, let alone to fix, so dumping it was a good thing anyway).